# Rubocop UniqueValidationWithoutIndex with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

Rubocop has a uniqueness validator if the index is missing. So if validation for uniqueness is present, it searches for indexes in the schema. I don't get how does it work with scopes.

My model validations:

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :group_id }, length: { maximum: 20 }
validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :group_id }
```

Added indexes on columns:

```
 add_index :rss_sources, [:url, :group_id], unique: true
 add_index :rss_sources, [:name, :group_id], unique: true
```

Rubocop is returning an error:

```
Rails/UniqueValidationWithoutIndex: Uniqueness validation should be with a unique index.
```

**How to handle unique indexes when scope is present?**

Comment: This looks like a bug in the cop as both the validation and index are properly defined.

Comment: @max I also think that

Comment: I'm assuming you have run the migration? Did you check the issues on Github? If one doesn't exist I would consider creating it.

Comment: What version of rubocop are you running? Running 0.92 I don't see the issue with similar scoped validations. As @max indicated, you might also check your ``schema.rb`` to ensure the migrations have run successfully and the indexes appear. there.

Comment: Yes, I run all migrations first. @rmlockerd I'm using 0.82 version, maybe upgrading will solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: @rmlockerd yup, upgrading did solve the problem!